# Knockout: changing options in select list without clearing value in view-model

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, viewmodel, cascadingdropdown

I have a Knockout JS based problem with some cascading options lists and switching out the underlying "active" object that they relate to.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DanMcCoy/5mpwx501/6/) to demonstrate the problem.

I have a UI in which the users are editing a main "header" record and adding/removing/editing child records. There is a central area for editing child records. The idea is to click a child record in a table and this become the record being edited in the middle area.

The problem I have is due to the fact that the list of things in the second drop-down changes depending on the first. This is fine until the active record changes. If the category changes because the active record changes then the list of "things" also changes. At this point, the chosen "thing" (2nd drop-down) on the new active child record is cleared.

I'm assuming the value on the new active record changes, but is cleared because it doesn't appear in the old list (if the category changed). The list of items themselves is then changed (including the appropriate value), but the value has already gone from the view model by this point.

(I realize that's quite a long-winded explanation, hopefuly the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DanMcCoy/5mpwx501/6/) makes it clear)

How can I change the list of items in a drop-down AND the selected value in the view model without losing the selected value along the way?

HTML:

```
<label>Some header field</label>
<input type="text" id="txtSomeHeaderField" data-bind="value: HeaderField" />

<fieldset>
    <legend>Active Child Record</legend>

    <label>Category</label>
    <select id="ddlCategory" data-bind="options: categories, value: ActiveChildRecord().Category, optionsCaption:'Select category...'" ></select>

    <label>Things</label>
    <select id="ddlThings" data-bind="options: ThingsList, value: ActiveChildRecord().Favorite, optionsCaption:'Select favorite thing...'" ></select>
</fieldset>

<button data-bind="click: AddChildRecord" >Add a child record</button>

<table id="tblChildRecords" border>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Favorite Thing</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ChildRecords">
        <tr data-bind="click: ChildRecordClicked, css: {activeRow: ActiveChildRecord() === $data}" >
            <td data-bind="text: Category"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Favorite"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>Steps to reproduce problem:</p>
<ol>
    <li>Click "Add child record"</li>
    <li>Click on that row to make it the "active" record</li>
    <li>Choose category "Pets" and thing "Dog"</li>
    <li>Click "Add child record"</li>
    <li>Click on the new row to make it the "active" record</li>
    <li>Choose category "Colours" and thing "Blue"</li>
    <li>Now click back on the first row... <strong>"Dog" disappears!</strong></li>
</ol>
```

Javascript:

```
var categories = ["Pets", "Colours", "Foods"];

var MyViewModel = function(){
    var _this = this;

    this.HeaderField = ko.observable("this value is unimportant");
    this.ChildRecords = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.ActiveChildRecord = ko.observable({ Category: ko.observable("-"), Favorite: ko.observable("-")});    
    this.ThingsList = ko.observableArray();

    this.AddChildRecord = function(){
        _this.ChildRecords.push({ Category: ko.observable("-"), Favorite: ko.observable("-")});
    }

    this.ChildRecordClicked = function(childRecord){
        _this.ActiveChildRecord(childRecord);
    }

    this.RefreshThingsList = ko.computed(function(){
        var strActiveCategory = _this.ActiveChildRecord().Category();
        switch(strActiveCategory){
            case "Pets": _this.ThingsList(["Dog", "Cat", "Fish"]); break;      
            case "Colours": _this.ThingsList(["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange"]); break;
            case "Foods": _this.ThingsList(["Apple", "Orange", "Strawberry"]); break;
        }        

    });
}

ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel);
```

Comment: modified your fiddle you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/9edj1z64/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knockout's valueAllowUnset binding might be a cleaner approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/5mpwx501/8/

```
<select id="ddlCategory" data-bind="options: categories, value: ActiveChildRecord().Category, valueAllowUnset: true, optionsCaption:'Select category...'" ></select>
<select id="ddlThings" data-bind="options: ThingsList, value: ActiveChildRecord().Favorite, valueAllowUnset: true, optionsCaption:'Select favorite thing...'" ></select>
```

@super cool is 100% correct, but the reason it is undefined is that the **ActiveChildRecord** changes when you click the pet row, but this computed function has not yet executed so you've got a small timeframe where **Dog** is the Favorite, but the options are still **Colours**. Since **Dog** is not an option, the dropdown will set the **Favorite** property on your **ActiveChildRecord** to undefined.

I would use the valueAllowUnset binding. Basically it tells the dropdown that if there is no match, don't set my value to undefined, but rather wait because the options might be updating.

A nice side effect of using this binding is that when you add a new child record it doesn't copy the previous row. It naturally resets the selection for you.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! 
I think I may have even very quickly read about the "valueAllowUnset" binding on the Knockout site earlier today but obviously didn't take it in properly. Thankyou for pointing it out to me, it's very much appreciated.
This is the simplest, cleanest and most direct solution and so I'm marking this one as the answer.
Thanks to @supercool for also providing an excellent answer.

Comment: @kyle this was apt answer & avoids extra logic . `+1`  thank you for heads up .

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot give a +1, and I'm even tempted to give a -1. However I won't do it because it's intersting your mentioned of valueAllowUnset. There is an important, dangerouse side effect that must be taken into account and corrected in someway: if you click "add a child record", click on the row to select it and then choose Pets/Cats, it's alright. But if right at that moment you change your mind and choose "Colours" you get the wrong combination of "Colours/Cats" Oooops!!!! You have not control on it. In the other solutions this doesn't happen.

Comment: On the other hand, my solution is the only one that adds an empty record, and automatically selects it for edition, with both lists reset. Althoug I insist that it's always much better to edit the new record outside of the `observableArray` so that the user have the chance to accept or cancel it. If he accepts it (either implicitly, by leaving the editor, or explicitly, providing the user a button) it can also be validated before adding it to the `observableArray` (or replacing the edited one).

Comment: @JotaBe glad you came up with such a wonderful point on `valueAllowUnset` . very helpful (risky to use) .

Comment: @JotaBe is correct. That's some buggy behavior and for that reason if I were you I would implement his solution. However, the title of the question is how you can change options of a select list without updating the value of the model property, to which valueAllowUnset is the answer. Again, I would highly consider refactoring and using JotaBe's approach.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a totally different approach, using subscriptions to updates lists and values, and an special observable to hold the edited record.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Active Child Record</legend>
    <label>Category</label>
    <select id="ddlCategory" 
       data-bind="options: categories, value: category, 
                  optionsCaption:'Select category...'" ></select>
    <label>Things</label>
    <select id="ddlThings" 
       data-bind="options: things, value: thing, 
                  optionsCaption:'Select favorite thing...'" ></select>
</fieldset>

<button data-bind="click: AddChildRecord" >Add a child record</button>

<table id="tblChildRecords" border>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Favorite Thing</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: childRecords">
        <tr data-bind="click: ChildRecordClicked, 
                css: {activeRow: editedRecord() === $data}" >
            <td data-bind="text: category"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: thing"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var categories = ["Pets", "Colours", "Foods"];

var MyViewModel = function(){
    var _this = this;

    this.categories = ko.observableArray(["Pets","Colours","Foods"]);
    this.category = ko.observable();
    this.category.subscribe(function(newCategory){
        _this.refreshThings(newCategory);
        if(editedRecord()) {
            editedRecord().category(newCategory);
        }
    });

    this.things = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.thing = ko.observable();
    _this.refreshThings = function(newCategory){
        switch(newCategory){
            case "Pets": _this.things(["Dog", "Cat", "Fish"]); break;      
            case "Colours": _this.things(["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange"]); break;
            case "Foods": _this.things(["Apple", "Orange", "Strawberry"]); break;
        }        
    };
    this.thing.subscribe(function(newThing){
        if(editedRecord()) {
            editedRecord().thing(newThing);
        }
    });

    this.childRecords = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.editedRecord = ko.observable();

    this.AddChildRecord = function(){
        var newRecord = {
            category: ko.observable(),
            thing: ko.observable()
        };
        _this.childRecords.push(newRecord);
        _this.editedRecord(newRecord);
        _this.category('');
        _this.thing('');
    }

    this.ChildRecordClicked = function(childRecord){
        _this.editedRecord(null);
        _this.category(childRecord.category())
        _this.thing(childRecord.thing())
        _this.editedRecord(childRecord);
    }    

}

ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel);
```

Several notes:

- a new observable, named 'editedRecord' is used. This can hold the value of the currently edited record (either new, either selected by clicking it), or a null value, if nothing should be edited (this value is set in `AddChildRecord` and `ChildrecordClicked`, to vaoid changes while the lists are updated)
- there is an array of `categories`, a `category` observable, and a subscription that updates the list of things as well as the category property of the edited record, if present
- there is an array of `things`, a `thing` observable, and a subscription that updates the thing property of the edited record, if present
- the `addChildRecord`, creates a new, empty record, and set it as the edited record. Besides initializes both lists of categories and things
- the `childRecordClick` sets the clicked record as edited record

As you can see, with this technique the bindings remain very simple, and you have full control of what's ging on in each moment.

You can use techniques similar to this one to allow cancelling of the edition and things like that. In fact, I usually edit the record in a different place, and add it, or apply its changes, once the user accepts them, allowing him to cancel.

[This is your modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tx1m9xk/16/).

Finally, if you want to keep the slashes on unedited records, make this change:

```
this.AddChildRecord = function(){
    _this.editedRecord(null);
    var newRecord = {
        category: ko.observable("-"),
        thing: ko.observable("-")
    };
    _this.childRecords.push(newRecord);
    _this.category('');
    _this.thing('');
    _this.editedRecord(newRecord);
}
```

included in [this version of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tx1m9xk/17/), but it would be better if you applied an style so that the table cell has a minimun height, and keep it empty, like in the previous version.

Comment: just perfect . +1 for providing such detailed explanation bro .

Answer (score 1):

well i made a small modification in your fiddle which worked perfectly .

**View Model:**

```
this.RefreshThingsList = ko.computed(function(){
        var store= ActiveChildRecord().Favorite();
        var strActiveCategory = _this.ActiveChildRecord().Category();
        switch(strActiveCategory){
            case "Pets": _this.ThingsList(["Dog", "Cat", "Fish"]); break;      
            case "Colours": _this.ThingsList(["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange"]); break;
            case "Foods": _this.ThingsList(["Apple", "Orange", "Strawberry"]); break;
        }      
        alert(ActiveChildRecord().Favorite()); // debug here you get undefined on your step 7 so store the value upfront and use it .
       ActiveChildRecord().Favorite(store);
    });
```

working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/9edj1z64/)**

Just in case you looking for something other than this let us know .

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Although my specific problem was also solved by using the "valueAllowUnset" binding, I can imagine this approach also being useful for similar problems.